# Get rates data JSON from an API to be able to use the data in a graph with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm trying to get the rates data "JSON" from an API to be able to use the data in a graph. The graph itself functions once it gets the data right.
Is there a stage where I need to take the rates labels separately?

I am able to print out the rate in a test, but this means I had to define the currency: 
  `//alert(data.rates.AUD);`

This is how the JSON data looks:

```
// base "EUR"<br>
// date "2017-10-30"<br>
// rates    <br>
// AUD  1.5148 <br>
// BGN  1.9558<br>
// BRL  3.779<br>
// CAD  1.4918<br
// CHF  1.1603


src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
src ="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"

width = 600;
height = 450;

$.get(" http://api.fixer.io/latest ", function(data)
            {       
                var width = 500;
                var height = 500;

                var ratesD = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    ratesD.push(data[i].rates);
                }
                var widthScales = d3.scaleLinear()
                                        .domain([0, d3.max(ratesD)])
                                        .range([ 0, width]);
                var canvas = d3.select("body")
                                .append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width)
                                .attr("height", height);
                canvas.selectAll("rectangels")
                            .data(data)
                            .enter()
                                .append("rect")
                                .attr("width", function(data) {return widthScales(data.rates);})
                                .attr("height", 20)
                                .attr("x", 0)
                                .attr("y", function(data, i){ return i*100;});
            });
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with this right now?  Are you getting some sort of error?  Is there anything showing up in the console or on the networks tab when you try to run this code?

Comment: There is no error, the problem is that i´m not able to get the rates displayed. I'm 100% sure the graph code works. I'm just missing something when using the data from the API.